# Binding when element is instantiated in code behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have two properties that need to be binded. One is Value and it is the UserControl's property and the second one is property from an image element. The image element is inside Window. The Window is intestated in the code behind (UserControl).

What do I need to add to enable proper binding between image src and property Value. The code is shown below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="nnnn">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <propSheet:BitmapConverter x:Key="bitmapConverter" />

    <Window x:Key="imagePopup"
            Width="640"
            Height="480">
        <Grid Background="LightGray">
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource bitmapConverter}}" />

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"></TextBlock>

            <Button Grid.Row="1"
                    Width="25"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Click="OpenFile_Click">
                ...
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Window>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Click="ViewImage_Click">View Image</Button>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What??? this XAML doesn't work. You can't place a `Window` inside a `UserControl`... What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is not inside user control. It is inside user control's resource! It is a big difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set the Window's [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) property to the UserControl instance before showing it:

```
private void ViewImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = Resources["imagePopup"] as Window;
    window.DataContext = this; // the UserControl
    window.Show();
}
```